# angular-cli ng serve --- how can i stop its regular refresh

Tags: angular, angular-cli

After running `ng serve`,the browser will regularly refresh and the page will be reloaded.How can I stop it,so that I can debug.I see that it is the result of 'Websocket',so what configuration can i make to stop this regularly refresh.

Comment: Normally the refresh is with any change in the project files (js or ts) Please share some code.

Comment: But here I have not change any file,in browser i found two requests which will be send regularly:`ws://localhost:4200/sockjs-node/058/hu4yko1l/websocket`and `http://localhost:4200/sockjs-node/info?t=1490002839388`,and after the first request return the page will be reloaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ng serve --live-reload=false`

See here for more options you can provide to the command:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/serve.md

Comment: Great，after add this , the problem is solved,Thanks a lot ! I first found that wiki,but i only saw the attribute while didn't find that can have  value too! Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't update the code through web-socket. It just preserves the code without refreshing in browser. Any idea how to reflect code changes in browser without reloading the page?

Answer (score 0):

you can add at your package.json at script new command :

```
 "ng notreload" : "ng serve --live-reload=false"
```

and then run `ng notreload` at your cmd.

Comment: Good idea， without affecting the original one!